# Running leiningen for storm projects offline

Tags: clojure, apache-storm, leiningen

I am trying to compile some projects on the twitter storm platform using leiningen. The servers I am working on do not have access to internet. I was wondering if it is possible to work offline by making a local repository by downloading all dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you should be able to do this by just putting the dependencies where lein expects to find them and then it will use them instead of going out to download them. That said, I've never tried this.

It looks like the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10504076/how-to-force-lein-deps-to-re-fetch-local-jars-libs) pretty much points to how to do it:

1. Run `lein deps` on a machine that is connected to the Internet
2. Copy `$HOME/.m2/repository` to your server

and that should take care of it. However, I have not tried this, so there may be some problem with this method that I have not foreseen.